# erro cors no angular 6

Tags: angular, cors

Pessoal estou com esse erro em um projeto:

```
Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8000/hqi/pages: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

E não consigo resolve, segui algns exemplos que ensinavam a criar um arquivo de proxy:

```
const proxy = [
{
   context: '/hqi',
   target: 'http://localhost:8000'
}];
module.exports = proxy;
```

porem, não deu resultado o erro persiste, alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: vc tem que configurar  o cors no seu backend

Comment: O que você está usando no back-end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adicione o seguinte header na resposta do seu back-end.

`httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

Comment: no laravel insiro aonde sabe me dizer?

Comment: Procure o objeto que é utilizado como resposta para as requisições

Comment: de acordo com a documentação oque você me passo seria isso

    Route::get('home', function () {
       return response('Hello World', 200)
                  ->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
   });

mas trabalho com rotas assim

    Route::resource('users', 'UserController');

então não sei onde se encaixaria isso

Comment: isso, adicione o cabeçalho que eu citei na resposta no ->header('...')

Comment: Agora sim entendi oque faltou entender era onde eu colocaria isso, e seria no controller, agradeço a dica

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente o problema é no seu backend, qual linguagem está utilizando ? Você precisa definir o cabeçalho: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' com o valor '*' no seu backend, isso varia de linguagem pra linguagem, posta aqui o código do teu backend pra gente poder ter uma ideia.

Comment: back end é php com laravel e o front é angular

Mas ja busquei solucão no back end tbm e nao resolveu

Comment: pode postar o código do backend onde você pôs o cors aqui ?