# Angular: erro de CORS ao fazer requisição http GET

Tags: javascript, angular, api, http

Preciso receber uma lista de perguntas da minha API e armazenar em um Array no meu componente angular, ja fiz isso diversas vezes em outros projetos e sempre deu certo dessa exata forma, apenas dessa vez ocorre um erro de CORS nessa chamada em especifico. Existem outras chamadas na mesma API em outros components do meu projeto funcionando perfeitamente.

**Erros:**

```
1 - Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8080/perguntas' from origin 
'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin 
requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, 
chrome-extension, https.

2 - QuizComponent_Host.html:1 ERROR Error: [object Object]
at viewWrappedDebugError (core.es5.js:8422)
at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13477)
at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (core.es5.js:13007)
at ViewRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ViewRef_.detectChanges (core.es5.js:10174)
at core.es5.js:4812
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at ApplicationRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ApplicationRef_.tick (core.es5.js:4812)
at core.es5.js:4684
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke

3 - QuizComponent_Host.html:1 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 0, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
```

**Tenho um service da seguinte forma:**

```
export class QuizService {

 perguntasUrl = 'localhost:8080/perguntas';

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 listar(email: string, senha: string) {
   return this.http.get<any[]>(`${this.perguntasUrl}`,this.atribuirHeader(email, senha));
 }

 atribuirHeader(email: string, senha: string) {
   const username: string = email;
   const password: string = senha;
   const httpOptions = {
   headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password)
  })
 };
   return httpOptions;
 }
}
```

**E um Component:**

```
export class QuizComponent implements OnInit {
  usuarioSessao: UsuarioLogado = new UsuarioLogado();

  perguntas: Array<any>;

  constructor(private quizService: QuizService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.usuarioSessao = 
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usuarioLogado'));
    this.quizService.listar(this.usuarioSessao.email, 
     this.usuarioSessao.senha).subscribe(dados => this.perguntas = 
     dados);
  }
}
```

**Minha classe CORS Filter:**

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsFilter implements Filter{

private String originPermitida = "http://localhost:4200";

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    //resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", originPermitida); ESTAVA ASSIM!!
    resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

    if("OPTIONS".equals(req.getMethod()) && originPermitida.equals(req.getHeader("Origin"))) {
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS");
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Content-Type, Accept");
        resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException { }

@Override
public void destroy() {}
}
```

Comment: Configurou os headers de origem?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/335809/77268

Comment: Vou postar a minha classe de filtros de CORS aqui.

Comment: Fiz a alteração da resposta relacionada pt.stackoverflow.com/a/335809/77268 mas continua o mesmo erro.

Comment: Já tentou mudar `perguntasUrl = 'localhost:8080/perguntas';` para `perguntasUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/perguntas';`?

Comment: Funcionou com esta alteração, mas fiz um teste em outro projeto com a mesma requisição e foi sem o http. Estranho não?